# Get contents of article given URL

Tags: php

Given a page's contents (its HTML), how could I get the contents of the article?

For example, this website returns the contents of articles given a URL:

http://embed.ly/docs/explore/extract?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foxnews.com%2Fsports%2F2016%2F08%2F14%2Fryan-lochte-3-other-u-s-swimmers-robbed-in-brazil.html

However, I don't want to use their API. I've used `file_get_contents($url)`, but I have no idea how I would go about getting the contents of *just the article*.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to parse the output of `file_get_contents($url)` and keep the part you are interested on.

Comment: What about regex or the substr, strstr, strpos, .... functions

Comment: @OrryVandermeulen No, use the built in parsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: ^ even finding a possible dupe is already doing "their" homework/work.

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera There's no way embed.ly does this for every site. No matter what URL you enter, it will always return the correct content, even if it's some no-name blog or some incredibly tiny news station that no one's heard of.

Comment: No idea what you mean with that comment, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

```
$url = 'http://www.foxnews.com/sports/2016/08/14/ryan-lochte-3-other-u-s-swimmers-robbed-in-brazil.html';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="article-text">' , $content );
$paras = explode("<p>" , $first_step[1] );

foreach($paras as $para ) {
   echo $para;
}
```

here if you want to get contents with image also use article tag as used in their dom structure.

Comment: Hope `article-text` never has a `div` inside it.